I am not able to make the DropDownButton functional... Is there any way I could be helped
Scaffold(
      appBar: MyAppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0),
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Text('Total balance'),
                addWidth(3),
                Icon(
                  Icons.info_outline,
                  size: 17,
                ),
                const Spacer(),
                DropdownButton<String>(
                    value: 'View other balances',
                    items: [
                      DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: 'lol',
                        child: Text('lol'),
                      )
                    ],
                    onChanged: (value) {})
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

Please what could be the problem with the dropdownbutton
it gave me and error, and i didn't expect that

The value of the DropdownButton needs to be equal to one of the values among the DropdownMenuItems you have, or null

You would most likely want something like this:
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  String? selectedValue;

  final List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> items = const [
    DropdownMenuItem(value: 'lol', child: Text('lol'),),
    DropdownMenuItem(value: 'lol2', child: Text('lol2'),),
    DropdownMenuItem(value: 'lol3', child: Text('lol3'),),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: MyAppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0),
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Text('Total balance'),
                addWidth(3),
                Icon(Icons.info_outline, size: 17,),
                const Spacer(),
                DropdownButton<String>(
                  value: selectedValue,
                  items: items,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() => selectedValue = value);
                  }
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

with value matching an item of the list.
